# How to add sensors and cooling devices to thermal-conf.xml

Tags: xml, sensors

I have a Toshiba NB510-108 netbook with Xubuntu 14.10 installed. Under Windows 7 Starter, temperature sensors show values up to 45 degrees Celsius. Under Xubuntu, they show values up to 55 degrees.
I would like to use thermald to keep the temperature at 38 degrees.

My thermal-conf.xml file only contains one sensor of type TSKN and two cooling devices of types rapl_controller and intel_powerclamp.

sensors -u shows this

```
    user@user-TOSHIBA-NB510:~$ sensors -u
    acpitz-virtual-0
    Adapter: Virtual device
    temp1:
      temp1_input: 42.000
      temp1_crit: 110.000

    coretemp-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Core 0:
      temp2_input: 43.000
      temp2_crit: 100.000
      temp2_crit_alarm: 0.000
    Core 1:
      temp3_input: 43.000
      temp3_crit: 100.000
      temp3_crit_alarm: 0.000
```

Can anybody please tell me how to add the above sensors to thermal-conf.xml, and maybe also how to locate and add other cooling devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on this stuff as well ( just installed ) anyway I'll try to share what I have understood.

**In short**

Thermald can control cooling via **active or passive cooling devices as presented in sysfs** (path `/sys/class/thermal/`).
If you know you have any other devices that the ones listed in `/sys/class/thermal/`, you can add manually:

```
The best cooling method may not be in the thermal sysfs. In this case
thermal-conf.xml  can  be  used  to  bind a zone to an external cooling
device.
```

-> in the config you can specify a path to a device: `<Path></Path>`

**Debug and other info**

At the moment the best resources looks to be:

1 `man thermald`
 2.`man thermal-conf.xml` [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/thermal-conf.xml.5.html)
 3. [Ubuntu Wiki: Thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues)

Ubuntu documentation provides and example `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that you may want use instead of the default config.

To understand what is going on the first step is to launch the daemon in debug mode:

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

On my Ubuntu (using the wiki config file) I can see the daemon **automatically adds the sensors from `sysfs`**.
Try to check the first lines of the debug log, you should see something like this:

```
thd_read_default_thermal_sensors 
sensor_update: type acpitz
sensor_update: type acpitz
sensor_update: type pkg-temp-0
thd_read_default_thermal_sensors loaded 3 sensors
```

In accord with your `sensor -u` print I cannot see any active cooling device ( fan ):

- It looks that `sensor` was not able to find any software controllable fan, so I'm not sure what other methods you can add ...